# Chances of four people being drawn together

Tags: probability, combinatorics, odds

There are eight people in a golf group. There is going to be a draw to split them into two groups of four. There are four people within the group who would like to be drawn together. What are the odds of that happening?
For example the eight people are A B C D E F G and H. What are the odds of A C E and H being drawn together?
Thanks.

Comment: The probability is $0.01428571$.

Comment: @user2974951 That answer is incorrect: the value is twice what you report.

Comment: @whuber You're right, if you do not care about which group these people are in then it is double.

Comment: In R, code `sum(dhyper(c(0,4), 4,4, 4))` returns $0.02857143.$